# showing argumentoutofrange from caller

Tags: c#, debugging

I would like to know if there is a way to get the "ArgumentOutOfRangeException" from the caller of a method/function:

Been searching for this for days, and no luck...
Either rare, or bad choice of search parameters...

Example:

```
class Main
{
    struct XYZ
    {
        public int X, Y, Z;
        public XYZ(int x, int y, int z)
        {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
            Z = z;
        }
    }
    class ArrayE<T>
    {
        public T[, ,] data;

        public ArrayE(XYZ xyz)
        {
            data = new T[xyz.X, xyz.Y, xyz.Z];
        }
        public T this[XYZ xyz]
        {
            get
            {
                if (OutOfBounds(xyz))
                {
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(); // Error shows here in debug
                }
                else
                {
                    return data[xyz.X, xyz.Y, xyz.Z];
                }
            }
            set
            {
                if (OutOfBounds(xyz))
                {
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(); // Error shows here in debug
                }
                else
                { 
                    data[xyz.X, xyz.Y, xyz.Z] = value; 
                }
            }
        }

        bool OutOfBounds(XYZ xyz)
        {
            return xyz.X < 0 | xyz.Y < 0 | xyz.Z < 0 |
                       xyz.X >= data.GetLength(0) |
                       xyz.Y >= data.GetLength(1) |
                       xyz.Z >= data.GetLength(2);
        }
    }

    ArrayE<int> Data;
    public void Test()
    {
        XYZ xyz = new XYZ(10, 10, 10);
        Data = new ArrayE<int>(xyz);

        xyz = new XYZ(1,0,2);
        Data[xyz] = 2;


        xyz = new XYZ(1, -1, 2);
        Data[xyz] = 4; // I would like the debugger to stop here
        //As if I did this:
        Data[xyz.X,xyz.Y,xyz.Z] = 4 // The debugger would then stop at this line

        //Example of what I want
        int[] array = new int[10];
        array[2] = 1;
        array[-1] = 3; // This is the behavior I would like to happen when out of bounds, The error shows here.
    }
}
```

**Edit:** More Specific:
When I start debuggin, I want the debugger to stop at the line "Data[xyz] = 4;" where xyz is a invalid index, so I can see where it was called from, and not from inside the Data[xyz] get set function.

If a regular int[] would get an invalid index, for example -1, then the debugger would stop 
at that line, and you can look at the lines before the array was accessed, so it would be possible to find out why the index is what it is.
With the current setup, when an invalid index of xyz is used on the ArrayE[xyz], the debugger stops inside the get set, making me unable to track and figure out why the xyz is outside the bounds of the array...

Hope that it is more clear, as to what I'm asking about.
I could use try catch, but is there no other way? doing the try catch would quickly make the code unreadable and unmanagable, since the program is very large...

So how can it be done, if possible?

I am using Visual C# 2010 Express

Comment: looks like you have first chance exceptions turned on?

Comment: Don't really know where to find that, and turn it of...
Will have to google more to find out.

Is it possible to instead surround the get set function with something, than to disable it for everything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Running this code you posted it appears to be doing what you want. An example of caller catching and handling it below. If you wanted to handle these in your test function you would just move the try catch down.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Main m = new Main();
            m.Test();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.Write("Uh oh :O " + e.StackTrace);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: 
Okay, after looking at this I came up with a way to do what you are asking. You have to set a DebugerHidden attribute. example:

```
        public T this[XYZ xyz]
        {
            //add attribute here to say this function is 'ignored'
            [DebuggerHidden]
            get
            {
                if (OutOfBounds(xyz))
                {
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(); // Error shows here in debug
                }
                else
                {
                    return data[xyz.X, xyz.Y, xyz.Z];
                }
            }
            //add attribute here to say this function is 'ignored'
            [DebuggerHidden]
            set
            {
                if (OutOfBounds(xyz))
                {
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(); // Error shows here in debug
                }
                else
                {
                    data[xyz.X, xyz.Y, xyz.Z] = value;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Well, try and catch worked. But it is not exactly what I wanted. Is there no way to make the debugger show the error, without the "try catch" where the method/function was called, as I showed with comment in the code?

Hard to maintain and implement try and catch in a "large" program... but better than nothing.

Comment: if you just want to see the error at debug time, you could use something other than an exception. you could just use a Debug.WriteLine statement.

Comment: @tom I just edited the question to be more specific, because I don't know if we are on the same page?

Comment: still don't think this is quite what you want but I've edited the code sample. If you are just concerned with where the error is comming from then this may be a good choice, now its displaying the call stack where it came from.

Comment: After thinking through it and looking at what your asking, I've made one final edit I hope helps to get what you are looking for.

Comment: Awesome, just the thing that I need :D  
Finaly I can debug happily, Many thanks for your help!